# How is mortgage in Canada calculated?

Tags: mortgage, canada

I'm taking a finance course at a Canadian university. The teacher said this time-of-money is how the banks calculate their loans and mortgages. Out of the blue, I want to try how close the formula in school match up to the real world. Here's my scenario:

> Borrow $300,000 at 3% interest, to be paid over 25 years. By law, the interest is compounded twice per year. Payment is to be made bi-weekly (26 payments per year). How much is the bi-weekly payment?

### My calculation

I first calculate the periodic interest rate:

```
r = (1 + 0.03 / 2) ^ (2/26) - 1 = 0.001145934...
```

Then plug everything into Excel:

```
=PMT(r, 650, 300000)
```

The result is $654.83.

### Bank's calculation

I then go to TD Bank's [mortgage calculator](https://tools.td.com/mortgage-payment-calculator/) and plug in the parameters. The result is $652.90 (see pics below).

[image: TD Mortgage calculator]

### Question

How did the bank come up with their number? What did I do wrong?

Comment: There are slightly more than 26 bi-weekly periods in a year. 26 * 14 = 364.

Comment: @Nayuki Sounds like an answer to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Nayuki points out you have too few days per year as `14 x 26 = 364` meaning you miss 1 day per year.

This results in two errors in your calculation

1. Your rate is a little too big, should be `0.001143` by using this formula `(1 + 0.03 / 2)^(14 / (365/2)) - 1`
2. You have too few periods as you use `26 payments x 25 years = 650`, which should have been `(365/14) x 25 = 651.8 ~ 652 payments`

Solving for these to errors will fix your payment to match TD Banks calculations.
This is also clear if you look at the ‘amortization plan’ in the calculator.